# Collecting data for two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch, python-3.6

I am trying to use data from ‘NCR’ on two columns in my CSV. However it overrides each other and only presented the data in the column called ‘YesterdayTime’.

Is there a way to use the data from ‘NCR’ in both columns called `’ExTime’` and `‘YesterdayTime’`?

My Code

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],
                    "query": {

                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{"range": {"VT": {
                                            "gte": "now/d",
                                            "lte": "now+1d/d"}}},

                                {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}},
                                {"wildcard": {"user": "jane*"}},
                                {"wildcard": {"user": "kate*"}},
                                {"wildcard": {"user": "dave*"}},
                                {"wildcard": {"user": "rich*"}}

]}}},size=10)


csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Date',  'NCR': 'ExTime', 'NCR': 'YesterdayTime', 'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}

with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_names.keys(), restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
    w.writerow(header_names,)
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']

             w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Output - `EX time` is being replaced with `YesterdayTime`.

```
DATE         YesterdayTime      Name   Party   Period

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001    0        0

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001    0        0

20170908    08/09/2017 02:42    1001    0        0

20170908    08/09/2017 06:30    1001    0        0
```

The correct Output that i want:

```
DATE       YesterdayTime     YesterdayTime       Name   Party   Period

20170512  12/05/2017 15:39   12/05/2017 15:39    1001     0        0

20170512  12/05/2017 15:39   12/05/2017 15:39    1001     0        0

20170908  08/09/2017 02:42   08/09/2017 02:42    1001     0        0

20170908  08/09/2017 06:30   08/09/2017 06:30    1001     0        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries does not support duplicate keys. Your last occurrence of 'NSC' in header_names dictionary is overwriting the first.

Comment: Correct, how am i able to use NSC for 3 columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign fieldnames with a list containing duplicates.

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_file = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'])
    csv_file.writeheader()
    csv_file.writerow({'foo':1, 'bar':2})
```

test.csv contains:

```
foo,bar,bar,bar
1,2,2,2
```

However that does not fix the problem if you want different header names...

Comment: the write row is using the variable called header_names so the above code might work on a small scale but for me i will be adding more columns later. is there a way with my above code it use that and come up with a solution?